# Can't add guides in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, guides

I can't add guides in Sketch.
I've tried to hover on a rulers and a red guide is showing but nothing happens on a click or double click. I simply can't add a standard guide. Lol :)

Someone, please help.

Comment: It looks like you should be talking to support for this one. Were you able to add guidelines before, or has it been like this ever since you installed Sketch? Are you running the latest version?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a tech support question. Please review the help files of the relevant software or turn to their help channels.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem, but I could use the trackpad's double click to add a guide, not with the wacom pen.
Unless, I set the fun-key on the pen to be double-click, that worked as well.